# pass laravel query to crud Trait

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Crud Traits From My controllers To Save Time How Can I pass query To From Controller To Trait

i tried this code but I get an error Constant expression contains invalid operations

```
/**
 * The entities to eager load on every query.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $withEntities= [
    'shipment'=> Shipment::query()->find($request['shipment_id']),
    
];
```

So I can use it in traits like this

```
trait HasCrudActions
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view("{$this->viewPath}.index")->with($this->withEntities);
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't be ?  `protected $withEntities= [
    'shipment'=> Shipment::query()->find($request->input('shipment_id')),
    
];`

Comment: @ManuelGlez Still getting Same Error 
expression is not allowed as field default value

Comment: You can use a function that returns the array. As a side note, it  looks like it's more suitable for a scope.

Comment: @Donkarnash How I Want to return Entities in compact

Comment: Can't understand the context. Could you please elaborate on use case? Where do  you use **$withEntities** and where it's defined -  code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can have a method in the controller

```php
protected function withEntities($request)
{
    return [
        'shipment' => Shipment::query()->find($request->input('shipment_id')),
    ];
}
```

Then in trait you can use the method

```php
trait HasCrudActions
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view("{$this->viewPath}.index")
            ->with($this->withEntities($request));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kareimovich Does this work for you? A method will give you more flexibility in terms of complex queries etc. When using method, unlike array property, you are not restricted to constant expressions and can still return array for use in the trait.